# Isolated Storage and Process Elevation

Tags: c#, .net, uac, isolatedstorage

I've built a program that included a built-in updater. The updater downloads the files to Isolated Storage and then relaunchs it's self with elevated rights to copy the files over. My problem is that the location Isolated Storage gives is different when a program is running elevated and when it's not so it sees no files to copy over. Is there a way to have Isolated storage not change the location between elevated an non-elevated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net isolated storage is application and user specific, elevating privileges changes the user and so the location of the isolated storage. A better solution would be to elevate privileges before downloading the updates.